# Android UI is getting blocked by AsyncTask and crashes occasionally

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

[image: MainFragment]

They all are nested fragments with `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`. Each fragment has `ListView` inside it so they get call together when ever I call this fragment and now I'm getting an issue of slow processing of app when I replace this fragment with other fragments or when i call this activity from other activities. Even sometimes my app goes in background without any dialogue and Home screen of android phones shows.

Code of each Fragment which comes under this TabLayout is as:

```
public class IndicesFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
public static String imagepath = null;
static ArrayList<EquityDetails> catListDao = new ArrayList<EquityDetails>();
static ArrayList<EquityDetails> catListDao1 = new ArrayList<EquityDetails>();
static int count = 0;
static int count1 = 0;
ListView list;
ImageView progressBar;
View view;
Activity act;
AdvisorsAdapter adapter;
TextView empty_text;
private boolean isViewShown = false;
AnimatorSet set;
FetchAllData myTask;

public static IndicesFragment newInstance() {
    return new IndicesFragment();
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        isViewShown = true;
        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.filter("");
        }
    } else {
        isViewShown = false;
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.equity_activity, container, false);
    act = this.getActivity();
    Constants.check_fragment_visible = 1;
    count++;
    return view;
}


public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState1) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState1);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_equity);
    empty_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.empty);
    progressBar = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getActivity(), R.animator.fadein);
    set.setTarget(progressBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
        if (catListDao.size() > 0) {
            adapter = new AdvisorsAdapter(act, R.layout.custom_equity, catListDao, 0);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            if (!isViewShown) {
                new FetchAllData(getActivity(), 3).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
            }
        }
    } else {
        CustomToast toast = new CustomToast(getActivity(), "There is no internet connection!");
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Constants.check_fragment_visible = 1;
    if (Constants.check_reload) {
        if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
            new FetchAllData(getActivity(), 3).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        } else {
            CustomToast toast = new CustomToast(getActivity(), "There is no internet connection!");
        }
    }
    if (adapter != null) adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

`FetchdataClass` which fetches the data from service and add into `ListView` is as :

```
public class FetchAllData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
ProgressDialog pDialog;
int typeId;
private Context cont;

public FetchAllData(Context con, int typeId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.cont = con;
    this.typeId = typeId;
    Log.d("Constructor Called", "yes");
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return getString();
}

private String getString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    URL obj = null;
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    try {
        obj = new URL(Constants.AppBaseUrl + "/call_listing/" + typeId);
        String userPassword = "oi" + ":" + "kl";
        String header = "Basic " + new String(android.util.Base64.encode(userPassword.getBytes(), android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP));
        con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.addRequestProperty("Authorization", header);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");


        // For POST only - BEGIN
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();

        os.flush();
        os.close();
        // For POST only - END

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            Log.i("TAG", response.toString());
            return response.toString();

        } else {
            Log.i("TAG", "POST request did not work.");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (con != null) {
            con.disconnect();
        }
    return null;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);


    if (result != null) {
        //    pDialog.dismiss();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        JSONObject jsonObject;
        try {
            catListDao = new ArrayList<EquityDetails>();
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("list");

            Log.d("Length ", "" + jsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                EquityDetails allDirectory = new EquityDetails();
                allDirectory.setEntry_value(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("entry"));
                allDirectory.setSerial_value(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("sl"));
                allDirectory.setTg_value1(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("tgt_1"));
                allDirectory.setTg_value2(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("tgt_2"));
                allDirectory.setMainTitle_value(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("script"));
                allDirectory.setMain_subTitle_value(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("exchange"));
                allDirectory.setRating_value(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("rating"));
                allDirectory.setReview_value(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("review"));
                allDirectory.setImage1(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("advisor_image"));
                allDirectory.setPosted_by(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("posted_by"));
                allDirectory.setImage2(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("script_image"));
                allDirectory.setCall_id(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("call_id"));
                allDirectory.setBuy(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("buy_sentiment"));
                allDirectory.setSell(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("sell_sentiment"));
                allDirectory.setRecommend(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("recommendation"));
                allDirectory.setPosted_date(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("posted_date"));
                allDirectory.setExpiry_date(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("expiry_date"));
                catListDao.add(allDirectory);
            }
            catListDao1 = catListDao;
            ab = true;
            adapter = new AdvisorsAdapter(act, R.layout.custom_equity, catListDao, 0);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    //pDialog.dismiss();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}


}
```

I'm using `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` to call webservice in background not again when `Fragment` is visible.

My Stacktrace when app gets closed without any popup is like as:

```
  1-29 12:10:49.580 10853-10863/com.cws.advisorymandi W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10.409ms
   01-29 12:10:49.707 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:27] Constructor
   01-29 12:10:49.711 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:241] attach
   01-29 12:10:49.711 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
   01-29 12:10:49.716 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi W/AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
   01-29 12:10:49.717 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:56] isActive: false
   01-29 12:10:49.726 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
   01-29 12:10:49.726 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi W/art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
   01-29 12:10:49.812 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:241] attach
   01-29 12:10:49.832 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:241] attach
   01-29 12:10:49.833 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi I/Choreographer: Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
   01-29 12:10:50.075 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 10853
   01-29 12:10:50.610 10853-10863/com.cws.advisorymandi W/art: Suspending all threads took: 43.636ms
   01-29 12:10:50.621 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
   01-29 12:10:50.630 10853-10853/com.cws.advisorymandi I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
```

Comment: You are running an AsyncTask on the UI thread?

Comment: Yes its in main thread. Do you have any idea to solve it?

Comment: Why? Of course that will block the UI. The **whole purpose** of an AsyncTask is to not run on the UI thread

Comment: But I'm doing whole work of network connection in its `doInBackground`

Comment: That's just a method name. That doesn't mean in runs in the background... It could say `doStuff`. You're  executing your AsyncTask from `getActivity().runOnUiThread`.

Comment: If it was is main thread it should've been given me an exception of `Network in main thread`

Comment: It would if you didn't disable strict mode... `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();`

Comment: oh yea, right. What will be the alternative of it then?

Comment: Don't execute the AsyncTask on the UI thread. Problem solved. Is the AsyncTask an inner class to the Fragment? I see the list variable and stuff, but they aren't initialized in the AsyncTask

Comment: yes, it's the inner class of the Fragment.

Comment: Where should I run it then? Because `AsyncTasks` run on UI thread as I know.

Comment: No they only run on UI if you make them do so like it the code you've posted

Comment: What is the purpose of `executeOnExecutor` vs just the execute method?

Comment: Are there is no error in the log you posted

Comment: there is no error. I just get warning type messages of `suspending threads` when my app gets stopped and comes to the home screen

Comment: Sounds like the operating system is killing the app because of a memory leak

Comment: Ok then I try to remove unused objects.

Comment: Try closing the HttpURLConnection variable and any other of those types of resources. I don't mean unused variables

Comment: oh Alright. i try and let you know then.

Comment: If that doesn't work, maybe try making a smaller, simpler example (start from scratch, if you must). If you hit the same problem, update your question with the smaller code, and I'd be willing to run the example app myself

Comment: ok thanks for your support. I'll let you know soon.

Comment: @cricket_007 I just checked and found that I'm closing it in each `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I don't see `con.close()` i see you close `in` and `out` and `os`

Comment: wait I update that code too.

Comment: I disconnect the `HttpUrlConnection` now after getting the data.

Comment: Okay. How big is the JSON response? That's the only other thing that could cause a hang up or a memory crash that I see

Comment: `JSON response` isn't that long right now. But in future it'll be huge. I commented the part of calling webservices and still it took few seconds when I called this `TabFragment` layout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102871/discussion-between-anshul-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 0):

Are you suer the data you're parsing in the "onPostExecute" method is not too large. Please note that "onPostExecute" gets executed on the main thread and thus can result in unresponsive behavior if the data-set you're parsing is large.

I suggest that you move the data parsing code to "doInBackground" as well and only set the adapter in the "onPostExecute". That might help a bit.

Comment: Right now, it's not too large but it'll be thats why I'm not doing parsing work in `doInBackground`

Comment: Hi Anshul. don't understand what you mean exactly. But, I think you agree that if the data-set is large, then you *should* also perform the parsing in the "doInBackground" method.

Comment: Do you think it'll solve the problem of suspending threads and app will work fast too?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Please try the following
a) Move the parsing to "doInBackground"
b) Start the network operations on "onCreateView" and not in "onActivityCreated"
It should give you some performance boost!

Comment: Ok let me give a try to your answer too.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed that you're starting the Network operations on the "onActivityCreated" method of the Fragment.

I suggest that you do this in "onCreateView". Therefore, you'll start the downloads when the view is created only and not when the activity gets created.

I also noticed that your log specifically says 
*"Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."*

That's an indication where too much of processing is actually done on the main thread.

Comment: I'm following it first.

Comment: Hi Anshul, If neither of them helps, maybe it's time to have a thorough look at your code to see whether something other than the Networking is causing the unresponsive behaviour. 
I suggest that you take a "divide and conquer" approach into this. ie: First load the fragments with static data and see whether the issue exists. If so, then there is something wrong with your UI related code. If the UI works well after removing the networking code, then there is something we need to look into the Networking part of your app!

Comment: I think there are 2 errors with both. Because I commented code from where web services gets called. It was working lil fast but not very fast.

Comment: Hi Ruchira, why don't you tell me a thing how we close these `AsyncTasks` in `onPause` and restart in `onResume`? It'll be a suitable answer too.